# Javascript - onClick event passing same parameter to function

Tags: javascript, html

I am iterating over elements in a container and adding onClick to every element. I wish to execute a method which accepts an id as parameter when I click on an element. The id is unique to each element.

**Below is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var conElement = document.getElementById("my-container");
    if (conElement)
    {
        var bookElements = conElement.getElementsByClassName("book-elements");

        for (var element = bookElements.length; element--; )
        {
            var bookElement = bookElements[element];
            var bookId = bookElement.getAttribute('book-id');

            alert ('Book id is ' + bookId);
            bookElement.onclick = function() {showBookSummary(bookId)};
        }
    }

});

function showBookSummary(bookId)
{
    alert ('Book id inside showBookSummary is ' + bookId);
}
```

**Issue:** Same book id is passed everytime I click on any element. Suppose I have 3 elements and id for 1st element is "123", 2nd element is "456" and 3rd element is "789". Whenever I click on any of the 3 elements, it always passes id "123" as bookId to showBookSummary function.

Am I missing anything in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

Your issue is caused because `bookId` is a regular JS variable that retains its value. Instead of saving the `bookId` of that book, the bookId is what it is after running the code.

The code execution would be as follows:

```
bookId = 789 (id of first book because you are starting at top and decrementing)
bookId = 456 (second element)
bookId = 123 (third element)
```

And then `bookId` is still 123, because you are still using the `bookId` variable. Therefore, anytime you call:

```
showBookSummary(bookId);
```

`bookId` is *still* 123.

---

**SOLUTION**

Instead, I think you should change the line:

```
bookElement.onclick = function() {showBookSummary(bookId)};
```

to:

```
bookElement.onclick = (function(t){return function(){showBookSummary(t);};})(bookId);
```

*edit*: onclick handler credits to @RobG from comments. Yes, I realize now that putting it as a string wouldn't work. This does something similar by substituting `bookId` for `t` and essentially storing the correct `bookId` instead of using the variable that changes during execution.

**EDIT: Possibly easier solution**:

According to the other SO answer (marked duplicate), it also seems that the relatively new `let` keyword could also help in this context. It creates a variable local to the scope of the *loop*, not the *function*. So if you just change the declaration of `bookId`:

```
var bookId = ...
```

to `let`:

```
let bookId = ...
```

This should work as well. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising.

---

On a side note, if you are using jQuery, you can replace the dreaded:

```
document.getElementById("id")
document.getElementsByClassName("class")
for(var element = bookElements.length; element--; )
getAttribute("attr")
element.onclick = function()
```

with jQuery's built-in shorthands:

```
$("#id")
$(".class")
elements.each(
attr("attr")
elements.click(function()
```

Comment: No, don't do that. The OP should break the closure using something like: `...onclick = (function(t){return function(){showBookSummary(t)})(bookId)`.

Comment: @RobG Why shouldn't this be done? What is the benefit of your handler function?

Comment: @Jonathan - If I use "function() {showBookSummary(" + bookId + ")}"; as string, my click event doesn't work at all. Nothing happens when I click on the element. Should function() also be inside double quotes?

Comment: @RobG Never mind I get it now. tech_human I'll update post in a sec. Sorry.

Comment: @tech_human See my update (credits to RobG). Does it work now?

Comment: I think I understood what we are trying to do inside closure, but still some issue with syntax. It's showing error "statement expected" between "(function(t){return function(){showBookSummary(t)})" and "(bookId)".

Comment: Meanwhile let me check what does "let" do or how is it different from "var" :)

Comment: @tech_human Added three semicolons. It might fix it. (They weren't statements before, but they should be now.)

Comment: It works awesomely. Just missing one closing '}' in solution. Final - "(function(t){return function(){showBookSummary(t);};})(bookId);"

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan and @RobG!!